# ADO.net Entity Data Model issue 'error 2002'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I'm trying to add new ADO.net Data Model to My ASP.net MVC 4 project but i got this error :

> Error 2002: The EntityContainer 'bdAllTargetContainer' for the storage model specified as part of this MSL does not exist in MetadataWorkspace.    C:\Users\Administrateur\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MVC1bd\MVC1bd\Models\bdAll.edmx   Line 605:9

And this **bdall.edmx** file :

```
  600  <!-- C-S mapping content -->
  601 <edmx:Mappings>
  602    <Mapping xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs" Space="C-S">
  603      <Alias Key="Model" Value="bdAll" />
  604      <Alias Key="Target" Value="bdAll.Store" />
  605      <EntityContainerMapping CdmEntityContainer="bdAllContainer" StorageEntityContainer="bdAllTargetContainer"></EntityContainerMapping>
  606    </Mapping>
  607  </edmx:Mappings>
  608 </edmx:Runtime>
```

Note that I'm using Oracle as Database. So how to slove it ?

Comment: You're probably missing a reference to the Oracle provider.

Comment: Not really an answer but if it's at all an option, you might want to consider doing EF code first. I feel like there is a bit less magic involved. Though if you are stored procedure heavy it could be a hassle.

Comment: @R0MANARMY EF code first dosn't worked for me The Entity Framework 6 is not supported by oracle Provider

Comment: The error says that the `bdAllTargetContainer` does not exist? Did you check that the `bdAllTargetContainer` exists? Maybe there is a type or something like that. Also because mapping glues conceptual and storage models posting just mapping does not give enough information to tell what's going on. Post the whole edmx or at least relevant parts...

Comment: your store (SSDL) and conceptual (CSDL) models are not in sync. try validating your EDMX model.